# Rails has_many through query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have many-to-many relationship with User, Attachment and Form model.

I want to reach to attachments not belongs to a user. I will try something like this but did not work.

```
Attachment.includes(:forms,:users).where.not('forms.user_id  = ?', @user.id).references(:forms,:users)
```

I have tried more but did't find the correct one.

> user.rb

```
  has_many :forms
  has_many :attachments, through: :forms
```

> attachment.rb

```
  has_many :forms
  has_many :users, through: :forms
```

> forms.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :attachment
```

> Update:

I m still finding an answer

```
Attachment.includes(:forms).where(forms: {user_id: user.id}).references(:forms)
```

is working but where.not returns empty

I think where.not only looks the attachments related to forms not all of them

Comment: Can you show the actual associations of your models?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple:

The first (sub)query you will need is to get all the attachments the user *does* have:

```
subquery = @user.attachments.select(:id)
```

Then you can easily get all the attachments that *don't* have the id's from the subquery.

```
Attachment.where.not(subquery)
# same as
Attachment.where.not(@user.attachments.select(:id))
```

Leading to the query:

```
SELECT "attachments".* 
  FROM "attachments" 
  WHERE ("attachments"."id" NOT IN (
    SELECT "attachments"."id" 
    FROM "attachments" 
    INNER JOIN "forms" 
    ON "attachments"."id" = "forms"."attachment_id" 
    WHERE "forms"."user_id" = $1
  ))
```

Comment: Did you manage to find the error? Also, I'll delete my comments, they're a mess and won't serve future readers - you should too

Comment: I m still waiting, I will learn more about querying, I hope I will manage